# Realistic Friction in Blender Rigid Bodies

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

I'm trying to do a simple rigid body simulation with a ball rolling down a slope. It works properly, however, I want the friction to be realistic. If I set the friction too low, the ball simply slides without rolling, and if I set friction too high, the ball slows down a lot, unlike what would happen in the real world. I think this is because the vector for friction is acting on the ball directly instead of tangent to the contact point. What should I  do?

Comment: I can't recreate this. Can you upload your .blend file to https://blend-exchange.com/ ?

Comment: @Benus https://blend-exchange.com/b/N6k9eWzS/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, to Apply Scale to the Rigid Bodies in the scene that you would like to be affected.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! So many problems can be fixed by applying scale.